# Why is PyTorch slower than PyOpenCL, which is slower than Numba on GPU?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution, numba, pyopencl

I was working on a FDTD program that used the discrete Laplacian, which I can be implemented as a convolution operation. [From what I have read](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#more-about-pytorch), the main component of PyTorch is a tensor library optimized to perform operations commonly used for machine learning (such as convolutions). I was interested to compare it to other frameworks I have used, so I wrote a test program to apply the discrete Laplacian to a 1d array multiple times and compare execution times:

```
import torch as tr
import time
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
from pyopencl import array


#parameters
number_of_timesteps = 1000
number_of_elements = 10000000


#set up the inital conditions
torch_data = tr.rand((1,1,number_of_elements),dtype=tr.double) #torch convolution needs shape (minibatch,in_channels,iW)
numba_data = np.array([0] + list(torch_data[0][0].numpy()) + [0]) #add padding [0] for convolution. handled automatically in torch.
opencl_data = np.array([0] + list(torch_data[0][0].numpy()) + [0])


#test Torch
device = "cuda"
torch_data_a = torch_data.to(device)
torch_data_b = torch_data.to(device)
kernel = tr.tensor([[[1,-2,1]]],dtype=tr.double,device=device)
with tr.no_grad():
    start_time = time.time()
    for t in range(round(number_of_timesteps/2)): # /2 because each loop is two convolutions
        torch_data_b = torch_data_a + 0.1* tr.nn.functional.conv1d(torch_data_a,kernel,padding=1)
        torch_data_a = torch_data_b + 0.1* tr.nn.functional.conv1d(torch_data_b,kernel,padding=1)
    print("Torch GPU time:",time.time()-start_time)
    torch_data_numpy = np.array([0] + list(torch_data_a[0][0].cpu().numpy()) + [0])

#Numba GPU kernel
@cuda.jit
def numba_conv_cuda(x,x_new):
    gid = cuda.grid(1)
    if 0 < gid < x.size - 1 :  # Check array boundaries
        x_new[gid] = x[gid] + 0.1*(x[gid+1]+x[gid-1]-2*x[gid])

threadsperblock = 100
blockspergrid = (numba_data.size + (threadsperblock - 1)) // threadsperblock
x_a = cuda.to_device(numba_data)
x_b = cuda.to_device(numba_data)
start_time = time.time()
#actually run the kernel
for t in range(round(number_of_timesteps/2)): #again /2 because each loop is two convolutions
    numba_conv_cuda[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](x_a,x_b)
    numba_conv_cuda[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](x_b,x_a)
print("Numba GPU time:",time.time()-start_time)
numba_data = x_a.copy_to_host()


#test OpenCL
context = cl.create_some_context(interactive=False,answers=[0])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
mem_flags = cl.mem_flags
program = cl.Program(context, """
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable //enable double precision calculations
    __kernel void update_psi(__global const double *x, __global double *x_new)
    {
        int gid = get_global_id(0);
        if(0 < gid && gid < x.size - 1){
            x_new[gid] = x[gid] + 0.1*(x[gid+1]+x[gid-1]-2*x[gid]);
        }
    }
    """.replace("x.size",str(opencl_data.size))).build()
x_a_buf = cl.Buffer(context, mem_flags.READ_WRITE | mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=opencl_data)
x_b_buf = cl.Buffer(context, mem_flags.READ_WRITE | mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=opencl_data)


#actually run the OpenCL
start_time = time.time()
for t in range(round(number_of_timesteps/2)): #again /2 because each loop is two convolutions
    event = program.update_psi(queue, [threadsperblock*blockspergrid], [threadsperblock], x_a_buf, x_b_buf)
    event.wait()
    event = program.update_psi(queue, [threadsperblock*blockspergrid], [threadsperblock], x_b_buf, x_a_buf)
    event.wait()
print("OpenCL GPU time:",time.time()-start_time)
event = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, opencl_data, x_a_buf)
event.wait()


print("Results are same?",np.allclose(torch_data_numpy,numba_data) and np.allclose(numba_data,opencl_data))
```

And these are the results testing on an Nvidia GPU:

```
Torch GPU time: 13.544365406036377
Numba GPU time: 0.2404193878173828
OpenCL GPU time: 0.9025869369506836
Results are same? True
```

I am surprised that the results show that a library designed for applying operations such as convolutions to be so much slower than Numba or PyOpenCL (which is not even optimized because I did not use any local memory on the GPU). Is this really the case, or did I do something wrong?

Additionally, why is the kernel written in c more than 3x slower than the kernel written in Python?

Comment: Is `torch_data_a + ` part out of GPU? Maybe data moves to CPU for this, then goes back to GPU number of iterations (1000) times? What is timing for just `tr.nn.functional.conv1d(torch_data_a,kernel,padding=1)`? Other tests take nearly a millisecond per kernel call but Torch has 12 milliseconds for pci-e data transfer perhaps? 10M double elements = 80MB, two arrays, 160MB. If it takes 12 milliseconds to copy 160MB, then it is 13-14 GB/s which is close to specs of pci-e 3.0 x16?

Comment: The timing for just `tr.nn.functional.conv1d(torch_data_a,kernel,padding=1)` is 0.556 seconds. I would expect some sort of caching of results to be a significant influence though because the arrays are not changing each time it is applied.

Comment: I believe `torch_data_a +` is on the GPU and not being transferred back to CPU because of the line with `torch_data.to('cuda')`  before the loop and not calling `.cpu()` until the end

Comment: Did you try making `0.1` in the `+ 0.1* ` part a tensor? Maybe not being a tensor but just a constant scalar number makes it create a CPU-array instead(by default maybe)?

Comment: I tried `scale_factor = tr.tensor(0.1,dtype=tr.double,device=device)` before the loop and multiplied by `scale_factor` instead of `0.1` and there was no difference in timing